# keeping a running count (rollup) with batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, stateful

Is it possible to keep a running count of all tasks by whoId in batch apex?  I want to aggregate all tasks for a contact, but how do you prevent the count from resetting after each batch?

```
global class TaskRollupBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful  {

global final String query;
global integer hqCount;

global TaskRollupBatch() {
    query = 'select Id, WhoId, HQ_Activity__c, Call_Report__c from Task ALL ROWS';
    hqCount = 0;
}

global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
{               
    for (Task t : (List<Task>)scope) {
        if(t.HQ_Activity__c && t.WhoId == '003e000000EQ8fm') {
            hqCount = Integer.valueOf(t.get('Id')) + hqCount;
        }   
    }
    Contact c = [select HQ_Total__c from Contact where Id = '003e000000EQ8fm'];
    c.HQ_Total__c = hqCount;
    update c;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9):

To do this you would want to implement Database.Stateful.  There's a great example of how to do this in the documentation

```
global class SummarizeAccountTotal implements 
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

   global final String Query;
   global integer Summary;

   global SummarizeAccountTotal(String q){Query=q;
     Summary = 0;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
      for(sObject s : scope){
         Summary = Integer.valueOf(s.get('total__c'))+Summary;
      }
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

   }
}
```

Here the link : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm